# Sitecore 10.0 use Sitecore Azure Toolkit to add SXA to an existing instance of Sitecore

Tags: sxa, azure, azure-toolkit

For Sitecore 10.0 (sitecore hosted) installed on Azure App Services what is the commandlet in Sitecore Azure Toolkit to add SXA the existing instance?

I have the file Sitecore Experience Accelerator 10.0.0.3138.scwdp.zip.

Answer (score 1):

All your combinations are provided in the [Quick Start Templates](https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore-Azure-Quickstart-Templates) Every version of Sitecore XM/XP has respective modules which can be installed along with the base installation of Sitecore, lets say you are installing 10.2 and your choice of the Version is 10.2 and did a XM0 installation. A Module needs to be installed along with it. Take a note of the following

```
{
"name": "sxa",
"templateLink": "<URL of the azuredeploy.json file of the corresponding topology *.azuredeploy.json>",
"parameters": {
    "cdSxaMsDeployPackageUrl" : "<URL of the WDP file Sitecore Experience Accelerator * CD.scwdp.zip>",
    "cmSxaMsDeployPackageUrl" : "<URL of the WDP file Sitecore Experience Accelerator *.scwdp.zip>",
    "speMsDeployPackageUrl" : "<URL of the WDP file Sitecore PowerShell Extensions *.scwdp.zip>",
    "solrCorePrefix": "sitecore"
}
```

}

Make sure you match the versions of Sitecore to the compatible version of SXA

**Modules is the additions you are looking for**